# Vim: How set a trigger function after input the symbol?

Tags: vim

I want set a trigger function for input symbol, but not an ':abbreviate'.

For example, a user wrote:

`function a(b)
           ^----- at this moment I want insert ' (' instead of '('`

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Do you want that each time you type `function something(`, it inserts a space before the parenthesis?

Comment: if I type `(` it inserts a space before if a space not exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add space before `(` every time you type <kbd>(</kbd>, you can remap it.
Add to your `.vimrc` the following line:

```
inoremap ( (<Left> <Esc>A
```